Open Angular component in new window with Electron
I'm working on an Angular app (version 18). I'm packing it with Electron and I need to open an app component in a new window.
This is my main.js file:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
let mainWindow;

// Function to create the main window.
async function createWindow() {
    // Define our main window size
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1250,
        height: 800,
        frame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        },
    })
    mainWindow.loadFile('./dist/my-app/browser/index.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(()=>{
    createWindow();
});



// Function to create the parameters window (child window).
function createParametersWindow() {
    let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
        show: false,
    });

    console.log("Creating parameters window");

    newWindow.loadURL('./src/app/parameters/parameters-index/parameters-index.html');
    
    newWindow.on('closed', () => {
        newWindow = null;
    });

    newWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        newWindow.show();
    });
}

The app starts correctly with Electron using command ng build && electron . and the main window works fine. However, when I click on the button which navigates to another component (the one I need to open in a new window), the new window opens but it's empty.
Looking in my dist folder, I see there are compiled files (dist/my-app/browser) and index.html. There are no files related to the parameter component I want to load (I don't know if that's correct or not).
Any help is much appreciated.

For anyone wondering, I gave up with Electron.
At the end I made I simple WPF desktop app with C# with a WebView in it. So much more flexible and much more less work required to get it working properly. Probably this is not the right solution for everyone, but since I needed to run it only on desktop Windows environment, for me this was perfect.

Your problem had nothing to do with electron tough. I am certain you are doing differently in your C# app than on electron. The problem you had was simply the URL of the window being the wrong one since you are pointing to src, instead of the built files. Also, from the look of it, you just display a simple HTML page, which should then be included in your assets folder instead. The blank page you were having was certainly because angular was loaded by could not find a Route with path '/src/app/parameters/parameters-index/parameters-index.html' or something similar
